# Data Driven Subscription to Linux machine

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to set up a data driven subscription to a `Linux` machine.

I'm able to access the network from my `Windows` machine using the credentials provided without an issue.  I have permission to write to a folder located on this network.  However, when I set up the data driven subscription I always get `The user account or password is not valid.` in the error logs.

I use data driven subscriptions might a bit and have no problem file sharing on my local domain.  Does anyone have any insight on what the issue might be?

Answer (score 0):

I believe SSRS account needs permission to a folder. Please check a link below for step by step process.

http://blog.softartisans.com/2012/08/09/automating-reports-with-ssrs-subscriptions/

Comment: Permissions are good and the data subscription is not working.

Answer (score 0):

in samba you can configure permissions with hosts, i.e. you might be able to access from your windows machine, but not from another server. so it could possibly be wrongly configured. can you check if you can access the share from the server?